# Bottom Navigation Bar Android Jumps on changing fragments

Tags: android, material-design

I implemented the bottom navigation bar using `Navigation Component`, it works fine when changing fragments using the bottom navigation bar. But when I navigate from within a fragment, it jumps and creates a white space - [gif](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XYQm_X7vA-U2YU1f-TulUUzOOx5V0UDr/view?usp=sharing)

How can I fix this?

Here is the XML for `activity_main`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment

        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_nav_bar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView

        android:id="@+id/bottom_nav_bar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu"/>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Edit :

This problem was caused because I tried to show and hide the top toolbar.

I used the following code to show/hide toolbar in the `OnCreateView()` function of the fragments
code : `(activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.show()` and    `(activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.hide()`

How can I fix the above problem without losing the hide/show toolbar functionality?

Comment: It's happening because of hide/show of `Toolbar`

Comment: Yeah, you are right. If I remove the code for show/hide the top toolbar, this problem disappears.  Thanks      But is there a way where I can show/hide the toolbar and not have this problem?

Comment: post `ToolBar` code

Comment: I have mentioned the toolbar code in the question

Comment: Any solution?...

Answer (score 2):

This might be a bit late, but perhaps helps someone else.

So, to solve this, you have to do 3 things:

1: Add the action bar as an overlay over your layout system:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```

This ensures that hiding the BottomNavigationView doesn't jump, flicker, or create any unwanted white space. Obviously, this will overlap your layout, so you could set a marginTop of the preferred action bar height.
So, so far no more white space and jumps on the bottom, but this leads to another problem, there will be a permanent whitespace when the action bar is hidden. Combatting this leads to the next point

2: Add an auxiliary view instead of a top margin of height exactly as of the action bar's:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_placeholder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_height" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar_placeholder" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_nav_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/bottom_nav_height"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:itemBackground="@drawable/bg_bottom_nav_item"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/nav_item_color_state"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/nav_item_color_state"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

We will show/hide this auxiliary view at the top of the layout, named toolbar_placeholder

3: Actually hide and show the toolbar placeholder:

```
myRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(object: RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    val mainActivity = requireActivity() as MainActivity
    var scrollDown = false

    override fun onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView: RecyclerView, newState: Int) {
        super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState)
        if (scrollDown) {
            // set toolbar_placeholder visibility to View.GONE
        // hide the action bar
        // hide the bottom navigation bar (preferably with animation)
        } else {
            // set toolbar_placeholder visibility to View.VISIBLE
        // show the action bar
        // show the bottom navigation bar (preferably with animation)
        }
    }

    override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)
        if (dy > 50) {
            scrollDown = true
        } else if (dy < -5) {
            scrollDown = false
        }
    }
})
```

PS: (you can try setting a marginTop anc changing the LayoutParams alltogether programatically instead of hiding and showing the toolbar placeholder View, but I chose the latter one)

Cheers!